# How to say that we know about sb/sth because of sth/sb?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, phrasal-verbs

I'm wondering which preposition to use in this sentence :" I know about him ... my friends" or " I know about this movie ... newspapers" to show that I know about these things because I saw them or heard about them from those things. Sorry if this kind of question sounds quite silly but I still dont master English very well yet.

Answer (score 2):

**[From](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/from)**, or **[through](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/through)** seem to work:

> I know about him **through** my friends
>
> I know about this movie **from** the newspapers

Alternatively, if you were to structure the sentence differently:

> I read about this movie **in** the newspaper